# Does Gatsby Offer A Way To Map Generic HTML Elements Rendered From Markdown To React Components?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, styled-components, gatsby

I would like to be able to use the components already defined and used in my Gatsby site, for elements rendered from markdown nodes. Using styled-components I have multiple components representing html elements:

```
const PrimaryHeader = styled.h1`…`
const SecondaryHeader = styled.h2`…`
const TextList = styled.ul`…`
etc
```

Is there a mechanism for mapping *generic* html elements defined in the markdown across to react components, so that a value defined in the markup as:

```
# Example
```

Is rendered by my `PrimaryHeader` component for example.

It seems the only option for styling markup is using descendent selectors to target elements within the rendered markdown content which feels clumsy and unnecessary when I already have components defined for rendering these elements.

Note that Gatsby [does support](https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/custom-components/) the mapping of custom components, but this involves custom html added to the markdown. I want the markdown to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, and i've added a [section](https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/custom-components/#mapping-from-generic-html-elements) to the Gatsby docs explaining how which is reproduced here:

**Mapping from generic HTML elements**

You can also map a generic HTML element to one of your own components. This can be particularly useful if you are using something like styled-components as it allows you to share these primitives between markdown content and the rest of your site. It also means the author of the Markdown doesn’t need to use any custom markup - just standard markdown.
For example if you have a series of header components:

```
const PrimaryTitle = styled.h1`…`
const SecondaryTitle styled.h2`…`
const TertiaryTitle styled.h3`…`
```

You can map headers defined in markdown to these components:

```
const renderAst = new rehypeReact({
  createElement: React.createElement,
  components: { 
    "h1": PrimaryTitle,
    "h2": SecondaryTitle,
    "h3": TertiaryTitle,
   },
}).Compiler;
```

And headers defined in markdown will be rendered as your components instead of generic HTML elements:

```
# This will be rendered as a PrimaryTitle component
## This will be rendered as a SecondaryTitle component
### This will be rendered as a TertiaryTitle component
```